# Editing a question displays "Posting question..."

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.26

When I edit a question and press submit I get a dialog box saying "Posting question...", when that dialog box closes I see a toast saying "Your edit has been submitted". The same doesn't happen when I edit an answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.28, thanks!